# Aligning horizontal list with another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, html-lists

I've been trying to align my navigation menu with a header image for a while with no success. I wanted the first and last elements of the list to be at the corners of their div while the remaining are evenly spaced. Sort of like this drawing:

[image]

I've tried to use float, margin-left/margin-right: auto, and displaying as a table but I still haven't managed to find a way that works and is responsive.

Here's my html code:

```
<div id="navbar" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 logo-img">
                    <img class="" src="images/header.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="nav-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="nav_projects" href="#projects">projects</a></li>
                            <li><a id="nav_about" href="#about">about</a></li>
                            <li><a id="nav_news" href="#news">news</a></li>
                            <li><a id="nav_contact" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

And the css (note that I'm using bootstrap so there's also the bootstrap css file that makes col-md-12 have 100% width):

```
.logo-img {
    height: 140px;
}

.logo-img > img {
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

.nav-menu {
    width: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

.nav-menu ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
} 

.nav-menu ul  li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.nav-menu ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I find most success using inline-block divs within a wrapper, with spacers between. Here is an example of what it might look like. I added alignment to keep the edges exactly aligned on the right and left.

https://jsfiddle.net/trmjjo4w/

Code:

```css
#title {
    font-size: 18px;
    width:300px;
    background-color: red;
}
#list_wrap {
    width:300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.list {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
}
.fill {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 17%;
    background-color: white;
}
#list2,#list3 {
    text-align: center;
}
#list4 {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">title</div>
<div id="list_wrap">
    <div id="list1" class="list">list1</div>
    <div class="fill">FILL</div>
    <div id="list2" class="list">list2</div>
    <div class="fill">FILL</div>
    <div id="list3" class="list">list3</div>
    <div class="fill">FILL</div>
    <div id="list4" class="list">list4</div>
</div>
```